# TCL/Expect script with if/else logic based on host IP address

Tags: script, shell-script, conditional-statements, expect, tcl

So I have been using and enjoying /usr/bin/expect for scripts because it can quickly log me into servers since it autocompletes my userid and password. Through some cursory reading, I've come to understand that it is basically a superset of TCL, which I admit knowing nothing about.

I ssh into my server all the time with my MacBook Pro, and I want to take my login script a step further and have it log into the NAS on my internal network one way if I am on my home network (with the RFC-1918 IP space of 192.168.0.0/24), and log into it externally a different way if I am not on that network. Basically an if-else condition.

A command to return the current IPv4 host address (at least on macOS) is:

```
ifconfig en0 | grep 'inet' | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }'
```

(Replace `en0` with the interface being used as necessary; it's the Wi-Fi on my Mac.)

This returns the IPv4 address. I was thinking this command should be called by some function (which TCL apparently calls procedures) and its output returned to an if-else condition that then executes the appropriate set of commands and exits the script.

I've got as far as doing simple if-else but I am not sure how the standard output from commands can be incorporated into the script. Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: You'll find it helpful to run through the [Tcl tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

To get the output of a command in Tcl, use `exec`:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605741/how-to-get-the-results-standard-output-of-a-tcl-exec-command
- https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm

For example, `set myvar [exec "date -u"]`